# How to split CSV rows then duplicate that row?

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have a CSV file from which I need to generate a new file with new rows. I have some experience in Bash and Python.

Example:

```
Source

Country A,Place1;Place2;Place3,Other info
Country B,Place4;Place5;Place6,Other stuff
Country C,Place7;Place8;Place9,Other examples

Target

Place1,Country A,Other info
Place2,Country A,Other info
Place3,Country A,Other info
Place4,Country B,Other stuff
Place5,Country B,Other stuff
Place6,Country B,Other stuff
```

So I need to split the 2nd column by the `;` delimiter and create a new line based on the rest of the information in the row.

Comment: `awk` is perfectly suited to solve this problem. Take the time to work thru relevent parts of the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html), especially the `split()` function and `for` loops. Then edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem. Include your current output and any error messages (exactly, copy/paste). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im in the usual situation at work , where someone needs this yesterday and ive been digging around and testing things with awk , sed etc to no proper avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Python 3 solution.  Note use of `newline=''` per [csv read/writer documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-contents):

```
import csv

with open('source.csv',newline='') as fin:
    with open('target.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        r = csv.reader(fin)
        w = csv.writer(fout)

        # Read original three columns
        for country,places,other in r:

            # Write a row for each place
            for place in places.split(';'):
                w.writerow([place,country,other])
```

If still using Python 2, use the following open syntax instead:

```
with open('source.csv','rb') as fin:
    with open('target.csv','wb') as fout:
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its always the second column. 
Change the columnNumber if its a different column (I'm counting this from 1 and not 0 for ease of use).

```
import csv
newData = []
columnNumber = 2
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    line = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in line:
        cStr = row[columnNumber-1].split(';')
        for i in range(0,len(cStr)):
            temp = []
            for j in range(0, len(row)):
                if(j==columnNumber-1):
                    temp.append(cStr[i])
                else:
                    temp.append(row[j])
            newData.append(temp)
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    writer.writerows(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a csv file then the simplest way is to open Excel, then navigate to File>Open and select "All Files" and navigate to the csv file you want to modify.  When you open this file, it should give you the option to state what character you want to use as the delimiter, and you can enter ";".

There should be a few more options that you just agree to, and then you will have an xls file with the fields split by the ";".

In order to get from this to the table you want, I would suggest creating a pivot table.  My answer is based on this being a one-off, whereas if you will have to repeat this function it would be better to write something in Excel VBA or Python.  Happy to advise further if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is very simple. Using this command

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," nest --explode --values --across-records -f 2 then reorder -f 2 input.csv
```

you have

```
Place1,Country A,Other info
Place2,Country A,Other info
Place3,Country A,Other info
Place4,Country B,Other stuff
Place5,Country B,Other stuff
Place6,Country B,Other stuff
Place7,Country C,Other examples
Place8,Country C,Other examples
Place9,Country C,Other examples
```